# Change NSImage brightness using NSSlider

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am working on simple image processing app, here is my unsuccessful attempt to change `NSImage` brightness:

```
- (IBAction)brightnessSlider:(NSSlider*)sender {

    ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[NSApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.contentViewController;
    controller.imageView.image = originalImage;
    CIImage* const beginImage = [self fromNSImageToCIImage:originalImage];
    filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, kCIInputBrightnessKey, [sender doubleValue], nil];
    self->filteredImage = self->filter.outputImage;
    controller.imageView.image = [self fromCIImageToNSImage:filteredImage];

}
```

Here is the implementation of `fromNSImageToCIImage` and `fromCIImageToNSImage`:

```
- (NSImage *)fromCIImageToNSImage:(CIImage *)inputImage {
    struct CGImage *cg = [context createCGImage:inputImage fromRect:[inputImage extent]];
    NSImage *finalImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cg size:NSZeroSize];
    return finalImage;
}

- (CIImage *)fromNSImageToCIImage:(NSImage *)inputImage {
    struct CGImage *cg = [inputImage CGImageForProposedRect: nil context: nil hints: nil];
    CIImage *temp = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage: cg options: nil];
    return temp;
}
```

Is it the right way to approach this? I don't even have a clue what is not working. Thanks.

**EDITED (I rewrote the code and there's a problem with sender value):**

```
- (IBAction)brightnessSlider:(NSSlider*)sender {
    ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[NSApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.contentViewController;
    CIImage* const beginImage = [self fromNSImageToCIImage:controller.imageView.image];
    CIFilter *brightness = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputBrightness", [sender doubleValue], nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = brightness.outputImage;
    struct CGImage* cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    NSImage *newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:cgimg size:NSZeroSize];
    controller.imageView.image = newImage;
}
```

It crashes when NSSlider is used - in this line: `CIFilter *brightness = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputBrightness", [sender doubleValue], nil];`

and debugger shows: **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6fbbba08)**

Comment: Can you tell more about "is not working"?

Comment: It seems that there is something wrong with `[sender doubleValue]` at least that's the part where my app crashes when I rewrote it. I rewrote the code like this - (post edited). Also the NSSlider values are between -1 and 1.

Comment: And when I switch @"inputBrightness" key to constant f.e. @0.1 it works fine.

Comment: Instead of `[sender doubleValue]` use `[sender objectValue]` which is a `NSNumber`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing faulty line to this: `CIFilter *brightness = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, beginImage, @"inputBrightness", [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[sender floatValue]], nil];` did the job.